# Store the records in an instance of a class and call the class from a Sub

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a combo box that I populate with records from a access db (user interface separate from database). What I'd like to do is store the records in an instance of a class throughout the life of the program rather than querying the table each time the user selects the combo box. The code fails in the calling Sub, it may be due to incorrect coding in the class.

This is how I'm connecting to the database:

```
Option Explicit

Dim DBCONT As Object

Public Function connectDatabase()
    Set DBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim strDBPath As String
    strDBPath = "C:\Users\rob\Documents\Cyber Security\Database\BackEnd.accdb"
    Dim sConn As String
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";" & _
                                "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                                "Persist Security Info=False;"
    DBCONT.Open sConn

    'Call closeDatabase
    End Function


Public Function closeDatabase()
    On Error Resume Next
    DBCONT.Close
    Set DBCONT = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

THIS IS MY ATTEMPT AT STORING THE RECORDS AS AN INSTANCE OF A CLASS. I GET AN ERROR MESSAGE TYPE MISMATCH WHEN ASSIGNING "Set getdevices = Rs" ANY IDEA WHY?:

```
Option Explicit


Public Rs() As ADODB.Recordset


Function getdevices() As ADODB.Recordset

    connectDatabase

    Dim Rs As Object

    Dim CurDatabase As Object

    Set CurDatabase = CurrentDb

        Set RS = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset ("SELECT * FROM tblCDA")

    Set getdevices = Rs

    closeDatabase

    Set Rs = Nothing

End Function
```

SUB THAT CALLS THE CLASS:

```
Private Sub cboSysDesignation_Click()


Dim rsDevice As Object

Set rsDevice = getdevices(Rs)  'FAILS AT THIS POINT!!! "Object variable or With block variable not set"

DeviceName = cboSysDesignation.Value

rsDevice.MoveFirst

    Do Until DeviceName = rsDevice.Fields("DeviceID")
        rsDevice.MoveNext
    Loop

        txtSystemDescription.SetFocus
        If rsDevice!DESC <> "" Then
        txtSystemDescription.Value = rsDevice!DESC
        Else
        txtSystemDescription.Value = ""
        End If
        txtSystemEngineer.SetFocus
        If rsDevice!ENGINEER <> "" Then
        txtSystemEngineer.Value = rsDevice!ENGINEER
        Else
        txtSystemEngineer.Value = ""
        End If


Set rsDevice = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote: *"I GET AN ERROR MESSAGE TYPE MISMATCH WHEN ASSIGNING "Set getdevices = Rs" ANY IDEA WHY?"*

Let's step through your code ...

```vb
Function getdevices() As ADODB.Recordset
    connectDatabase
    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim CurDatabase As Object
    Set CurDatabase = CurrentDb
```

`CurrentDb` is a `DAO.Database` object.

```vb
    Set RS = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset ("SELECT * FROM tblCDA")
```

The `DAO.Database.OpenRecordset` method returns a **DAO** recordset.

```vb
    Set getdevices = Rs
```

`getdevices` was declared `As ADODB.Recordset` but `Rs` is `DAO.Recordset`.  Their types do not match.

Comment: In other areas of my code (see below) the CurrentDb works fine: CurDatabase = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset

Set rsCDA = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblCDA")
Set rsGroupCDAs = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblGroupCDAs")

Comment: Should I change the DBCONT ADODB connection object to a DAO?

Comment: Hold on please, I'm still trying to understand your first comment.  Were `rsCDA` and `rsGroupCDAs` declared `As ADODB.Recordset`?

Comment: No they were Dim'd as Objects:

Dim rsCDA As Object
Dim rsGroupCDAs As Object

Set rsCDA = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblCDA")
Set rsGroupCDAs = CurDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblGroupCDAs")

Comment: But `rsCDA As Object` means that `rsCDA` *can* accept a `DAO.Recordset` from `CurDatabase.OpenRecordset` without error.  What was the point of that first comment?

Comment: I assumed CurrentDb was an ADODB.Database object becuase DBCONT was set as a ADODB.Connection object in Public Function connectData(). Was this done incorrectly?

Comment: `CurrentDb` and `DBCONT` are independent from each other.  Modifying `DBCONT`, or eliminating it all together, has no effect on `CurrentDb`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I adjusted the code and it works fine now.